# Asynchronous KendoUI Upload in IE 10 windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-10, windows-authentication

I have a Kendo File Upload control on a page that uploads some files to the server. 
The control is working fine on Chrome or Firefox, but on IE 10 there is a weird bug. It works if I upload files continuously, but if I leave the window inactive for like 1-2 min, the browser gets into a pending state.

Looking with Fiddler at what is actually happening, I can observe a 401 response received. There seems to be an issue with the Kendo control (or the specific environment I have) that has some sort of timeout and cannot authenticate the user, therefore we see that 401 response.

Environment specifics:

- MVC 4
- Kendo UI Upload Control
- Windows Authentication
- browser: IE10

Do you have a suggestion regarding this issue ?

Kindly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, same environment. For me it seems to be user specific. We have roughly 200 users, and I have 3 that are complaining. I sort of feel like there may be something messed up in their user profile, but I have nothing to prove it.

Comment: What is your execution timeout set to? If you increase do you still have problems? Also maybe post your controller code.

Comment: On the first request that got a 401 response, is there a Content-Length header? Is its value 0? On the second request, after that 401 response, is there a Content-Length header? Is its value non-zero? If so, are there any body bytes on the HexView tab?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter, but are you using Kerberos or NTLM as your Windows Authentication provider?

Comment: Please, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2980019

Does the patch help in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. The problem seems to affect only IE10 and IE11.
After some investigation and guesswork, I found a workaround that works for me.

Add this into the `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

I must warn that this may introduce other incompatibilities so please test everything else thoroughly.